# Stair newel post broken

Tags: repair, stairs

Newel post at the top of the stairs was extremely wobbly so I took it upon myself to check it out. After taking a better look I have come to find out that not the post itself is broken, but the apparent wood piece that actually comes off the bottom that I guess goes into the floor and is screwed was broken in half. After taking out a couple of screws I was actually able to pull the newel post out easily. How can this be fixed? Can I break out the piece left in the floor, and cut the excess off the bottom of the post then maybe somehow attach a new piece to go down into the slot? Please help.

Comment: A picture would really help of both the floor and the newel. The post could have a dowel added to it and set to the floor or the newel could have been cut at the bottom to act a a tenon and the floor drilled for the other half of the dowel or cut so it would receive the tenon part of the newel. A few good pics will aid in determining in what you have.

Comment: I've tried adding a picture but the website says even one picture is to large to post.

Comment: If the picture is over 2 meg in file size, it will not accept it. I also had an issue with uploading at one time even with teensie file sizes, I had to change a setting on my laptop, something like hardware acceleration, I think.